# Underline Volume and Number in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'd like to underline the *Volume* and *Number* of each citation. Currently I'm using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,citestyle=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,bibstyle=authoryear,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
```

Which results in

[image: Bibliography]

---

Here, I'd like to have underlined e.g. `86.1` in the first entry and `55.1` in the second. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general underlining is hard in LaTeX because the built-in `\underline` does not allow for line breaking and solutions like `soul` and `ul` cannot deal with arbitrary input. (For LuaLaTeX there is [`lua-ul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul) which generally performs much better.)

But since the text you want to underline would normally not be broken across lines anyway, we can use the good old `\underline`. In order to underline both `volume` and `number` in one, we have to modify the bibmacro `volume+number+eid` directly and cannot rely on field formats alone.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2,
  doi=false, url=false
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{underline}{\underline{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printtext[underline]{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\adddot}%
    \printfield{number}}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395." with volume+dot+number (19.4) underlined.]

Note that I did not add a test to check if there is a volume or number, because every regular `@article` should have a `volume` field.

Comment: Phantastic. See, I'm more into `Python` and regular expressions than `Latex` but need to get the paper done. Many thanks indeed.